# Why buffer size has no effect on this file read operation

Tags: java, io, buffer

I am learning about Java I/O. So using buffered streams reduces time taken to read or write because if you use normal FileInputStream , you are fetching one byte every time read is invoked but if you use buffers you will fetch specified size of data and store it in memory. So I tried to see this in practice.

```
package javaIO;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class BufferTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        int starttime=(int) (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);

        BufferedInputStream is=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/anil/Downloads/Vidoes/batman.mp4"),65536);
//      InputStream is=new FileInputStream("/home/anil/Downloads/Vidoes/batman.mp4");
        int a=0;
        while((a=is.read())!=-1){

            System.out.println(a);
        }

        is.close();

        int endTime=(int) (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);

        System.out.println("Took "+(endTime-starttime)+"seconds");
    }

}
```

I have set the buffer size for BufferedInputStream to 512,8192,65536. Each time it takes 87 seconds to complete the execution. So I tried using FileInputStream and still it takes 87 seconds to complete the execution. The size of the batman.mp4 is 24.7mb.

So what am I missing?

- Why the change in the buffer size has no effect on the execution time?
- Why the time taken for execution for both BufferedInputStream and FileInputStream are same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What slows you down is the printing - `System.out.println(a);` - you always print 24.7M chars to the screen. Try to copy the file to another location - read it with different buffer sizes and write it again to a new file.

Comment: In addition, the benchmark is invalid because it doesn't allow for the effect of cache priming.

Comment: I removed the print statement. For FileInputStream it took 9 seconds and for BufferedInputStream it took 0 seconds.

Comment: @SrimanthDuggineni - Remove the divison by 1000 of `startTime` and `endTime` to get measurment in mSec, for more accurate timing. You also may use `long` instead `int`.